# Number of possible zero entries in orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

It's easy to check that in an orthogonal  matrix $Q$ dimension $2 \times 2$    if there is entry $0$ in the matrix then necessary one additional zero must be present and the total number of zeros is $2$.

In an orthogonal matrix  dim. $3 \times 3$ number of zeros can be (if they are present) , I suppose from observations, only $4$ or $6$ - once again we obtain an  **even  number** of possible zeros.

Examples: 
$ \begin{bmatrix}   
0.6 & -0.8  & 0 \\ 0.8 & 0.6 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \ \ $ , $ \ \ \begin{bmatrix}   0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0  & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

- Can this observation be extended for other orthogonal matrices of
  greater dimensions?  The number of zeros is always even? How to prove this?
- Maybe, it is known the explicit formula for the  number of possible zeros in orthogonal matrices of any dimension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interesting observation, but it doesn't pan out unfortunately! It already fails in dimension 3. Wikipedia has the following counterexample of a rotoinversion:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & -0.8 & - 0.6 \\
0.8 & -0.36 & 0.48 \\
0.6&0.48&-0.64
\end{bmatrix} 
$$

(WolframAlpha agrees that this is indeed orthogonal, the example is from
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix))

Comment: Surprising example! Do you think that existence of such example is possible  only for number of zeros  $1$ or that also be possible to find, for example, for number $3$ or $5$? Can we show the all numbers for dimension $3$?

Comment: I don't think 3 zeros are possible in the 3-dimensional case. The column vectors form an orthonormal basis. If one vector has two zeros (and hence is a standard unit vector) , then the other have either two or none, by the same argument as in the 2-dimensional case. Otherwise they would all have one zero each, so the matrix would have to act on each standard unit vector as a rotoinversion restricted to a plane, which I don't think works.

Comment: What about $5$? Probably also not.  It 's hard also for me to  find an example with number of zeros $2$..

Comment: 5 zeros are impossible (for the 3-dimensional case). If the matrix has at least 5 zeros, then two of the column vectors must be standard unit vectors (up to sign). But then this forces the remaining column to also be a standard unit vector (up to sign), so that they form an orthonormal basis.

Comment: I see that  your counterexample give some insight for constructions of   matrices  with ($k_z=1$) :  the first column is   $ [0 \ \ a \ \ b ]^T$ , the second $ [-a \ \ -b^2 \ \ ab ]^T$, the third $ [-b \ \ ab \ \ -a^2 ]^T$ with additional condition $a^2+b^2=1$

Comment: We have also then the square of length for the second column $b^2(a^2+b^2)+a^2$ and for the third one $a^2(a^2+b^2)+b^2$ ..

Comment: **Two** zeros in orthogonal matrix are, it seems also impossible. Take two columns $ v_1=[ 0 \ \  a  \  \ b]^T $ and $v_2 =[c \ \ d \ \  0]^T$. Then their scalar product should have been zero, consequently it should have been $ad=0$ which generates additional zero. Taking this into account we have numbers $0,1$(your amazing  example), $4,6$ for dim.3.

Comment: At the end I would like to present a certain  orthogonal matrix generated according to the newly discovered (at least by me) rules listed above $\begin{bmatrix} -\dfrac {1}{2} & \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} & -\dfrac {1}{2} \\ -\dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} & 0 &  \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} \\ \dfrac {1}{2} & \dfrac {\sqrt{2}}{2} &  \dfrac {1}{2} \end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Rotations are orthogonal. Most examples of rotation matrices in any dimension will provide a counter example to this. In the $2 \times 2$ case consider
$$\begin{pmatrix}
Cos(x)&-Sin(x)\\
Sin(x)&Cos(x)
\end{pmatrix}$$
This is orthogonal for any $x$. There are many cases where there are no zeros.

Comment: Thank you Wintermute for the answer, but the question was for possible number of $0$ **when they exist**.  In dimension of matrix $2$ it is only one possible number $2$.